# Check sigin page is opened or not in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I want to make some changes on template(portlet.vm) in liferay based on some condition. And condition is to know whether user is signed in or not. Something like:

```
 #if ($is_signed_in)
         <section class="portlet" id="portlet_$portlet_id">
         ..
         ...
         </section>
 #else
        //Some other divs
 #end
```

I m trying to access $is_signed_in variable, but its not wokring. Kindly tell me solution of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah got my answer. To use $is_signed_in variable in portlet.vm, we need to include
     #parse ($init)

Comment: Good to know that you found out the solution in short span.